# Test with specific device?

Tags: android, crash, crash-reports

I have an app with many downloads and good reviews, but yesterday I got one 1-star review of someone. He said my app won't start on his specific device. I don't own that device. So what can I do to find out what causes the error?

I know I can see crash reports in the Google developer console, but that was just a review. I can still see what device he owns and want to improve my app that he would be satisfied and can start the app. What possibilites do I have?

Comment: Create an Emulator or use Genymotion as the default Emulator doesn't have some features that the Genymotion(paid version) have. If you know the device apply same configuration to the Virtual Device.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use BlueStack for testing. Make an android AVD having version that is causing the crash and then find the errors in it

Comment: Does a crash occur depending only on the device type or just the Android version? I mean is only the Android version mainly responsible if a crash occurs or not?

Answer (score 4):

Depending on the device it might be availible on [Amazons device farm](https://aws.amazon.com/device-farm/). It will save you from having to buy the device and you're able to build tests on the platform to fit into your workflow.

[List of current devices](https://aws.amazon.com/device-farm/device-list/)

Comment: Does a crash occur depending only on the device type or just the Android version? I mean is only the Android version mainly responsible if a crash occurs or not?

Answer (score 1):

use emulater,

there are so many emulators available in android studio.
Genymotion.
BlueStacks
Droid4X
Windroy

Comment: Does a crash occur depending only on the device type or just the Android version? I mean is only the Android version mainly responsible if a crash occurs or not?

Comment: yes Crashes depending on the version of the operating system using in the phone. like jelly bean, kitkat ,lolipop.